# How to skip the empty row added automatically to the DataGridView in a loop?

Tags: c#, datagridview

i have a simple c# application in which you have to enter data in a `DataGridView`. I have implemented some validators for the columns, like null values or non-numeric input. I do the checks after a button has been presses by `foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows) {...}`

i am facing the problem that it also tries to validate the last row of the `DataGridView`, although this one is added automatically and is empty. So i am stuck in a loop here...

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
    {
        string inputItemNr;
        string inputMHD;
        string inputCharge;
        string inputSupplNr;
        string inputPrnCnt;
        UInt32 itemnr;
        DateTime mhd;
        string mhdFormat = "yyMMdd";
        string batch;
        byte prncnt;

        if (row.Cells[0].Value == null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Enter item number");
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            inputItemNr = row.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
        }

        if (!UInt32.TryParse(inputItemNr, out itemnr))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Incorrect item number: " + inputItemNr);
            return;
        }

        if (row.Cells[1].Value == null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Enter MHD");
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            inputMHD = row.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
        }

        if (!DateTime.TryParseExact(inputMHD, mhdFormat, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
            DateTimeStyles.None, out mhd))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Incorrect MHD: " + inputMHD);
            return;
        }

        if (row.Cells[2].Value == null)
        {
            inputCharge = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyMMdd");
        }
        else
        {
            inputCharge = row.Cells[2].Value.ToString();
        }

        if (row.Cells[3].Value == null)
        {
            batch = inputCharge;
        }
        else
        {
            inputSupplNr = row.Cells[3].Value.ToString();
            batch = inputCharge + " " + inputSupplNr;
        }

        if (row.Cells[4].Value == null)
        {
            inputPrnCnt = "1";
        }
        else
        {
            inputPrnCnt = row.Cells[4].Value.ToString();
        }

        if (!byte.TryParse(inputPrnCnt, out prncnt))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Incorrect print count: " + inputPrnCnt);
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Please help.

Thanks,

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You could use the [`IsNewRow`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewrow.isnewrow(v=vs.110).aspx) property of the row:

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
{
    if (row.IsNewRow) continue;
    // rest of your loop body ...
}
```

Comment: This information was surprisingly hard to find through Google unless phrased just right; I had no idea this property existed until your answer brought it to my attention. Many thanks for sharing this non-obvious but surprisingly simple tip.